# Android - remove "active" marker from firebase database

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem with my project.
I want to remove specific google map marker, when I (for example) press button for delete. But I want to delete marker, that I will choose in my app, not all markers. My database looks like that: [Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZSfZ.png)

And everything, what I need is, that if I make marker active (probably, when I clicked on it), that I will be able to delete this marker from database and from map in my app. Code that add marker:

```
btnPridatKontejner = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pridat_kontejner);
        btnPridatKontejner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Welcome.this);
                    dialog.setTitle("Přidat kontejner");
                    dialog.setMessage("Prosím, zadejte typ kontejneru pro přidání");

                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Welcome.this);
                    View info_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_info_map, null);

                    final MaterialEditText edtTypKontejneru = info_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtTypKontejneru);

                    dialog.setView(info_layout);

                    dialog.setPositiveButton("Přidat kontejner", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();


                            final double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                            final double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                            MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

                            long date = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd. MM. yyyy, k:mm");
                            String dateString = sdf.format(date);

                            mp.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

                            mp.title(edtTypKontejneru.getText().toString());
                            mp.snippet(dateString);

                            mMap.addMarker(mp);

                            DatabaseReference markerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("markers");

                            String key = markerRef.push().getKey();

                            markerRef.child(key).child("long").setValue(longitude);
                            markerRef.child(key).child("lat").setValue(latitude);
                            markerRef.child(key).child("title").setValue(mp.getTitle());
                            markerRef.child(key).child("snippet").setValue(mp.getSnippet());

                            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtTypKontejneru.getText().toString())){
                                return;
                            }
                        }


                    });

                    dialog.setNegativeButton("Zavřít", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();

            }
        }
```

And this is my code for load markers from Firebase to my app:

```
mMap = googleMap;
    //Disable Map Toolbar:
    //map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef
            .child("markers");

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                String latitude_Display = ds
                        .child("lat")
                        .getValue().toString();

                String longitude_Display = ds
                        .child("long")
                        .getValue().toString();

                String title_Display = ds
                        .child("title")
                        .getValue().toString();

                String info_Display = ds
                        .child("snippet")
                        .getValue().toString();



                String latLng = latitude_Display;
                String latLng1 = longitude_Display;
                String title = title_Display;
                String info = info_Display;


                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng1);
                String titleInfo = title;
                String infoInfo = info;

                LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng( latitude, longitude );
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position( currentLocation );
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .title(titleInfo).snippet(infoInfo));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

Is it even possible to make something like that? Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
void del(String key) {

    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("markers").child(key).removeValue();
}
```

Pass the key of the marker which you want to delete.

Comment: There is the problem.. I want to delete any of marker, that I will create later.. Not only one, that I will specify here.

Comment: when you click on the marker then fetch the key for that marker and pass in the method.

Comment: Cannot receive symbol "key".. I think, that I paste it bad in my code..

Comment: You are adding one method in another method. So, that's why you are getting errors. Just call the method del(key) in onMarkerClick() and add the method in class.

Comment: I think that I am just an idiot.. Have I got it right now? Because I am still getting errors.. :/ I am really sorry, but I really don't know, where to put it.. :/ https://imgur.com/a/QpKtIcy

Comment: Just put that method in the class.

Comment: Can you just please write code here, as it should be? I really don't know, what to do.. :( Again, I am really sorry for your time spending to help me..